# Is $object_type truly required with register_taxonomy()?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

When registering a new taxonomy, the second argument of `register_taxonomy($taxonomy, $object_type, $args)` is the post type (or types) that this taxonomy is registered for.

However, when registering a custom post type, you can also pass taxonomy as one of the arguments:

> taxonomies
>   (array) (optional) An array of registered taxonomies like category or post_tag that will be used with this post type. This can be use in lieu of calling register_taxonomy_for_object_type() directly. Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with register_taxonomy().
>   Default: None

This is redundant. Which should be used? Can you register a taxonomy without associating it with a specific post type, and then later, when registering the custom post type, associate it then?

---

As a little backgrounder to why I should care (other than that I don't like inconsistencies and redundancy): I'm creating a fairly generic taxonomy that I can foresee using across a variety of implementations. I'd love to define this taxonomy once (in a separate file), without any foreknowledge of the custom post types that may want to take advantage of it in the future. Then, on a specific implementation, as I'm creating the custom post type, I know I have this taxonomy that I can associate with the post type. Hope this explains my reasons a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I dug into the source and discovered that even though the documentation STATES that `$object_type` is "required", there's nothing in the logic that makes this so. `$object_type` is just added to the properties of the tax object, which presumably is also done when you register the tax while creating the custom post, and also when you use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`. I tried creating a custom taxonomy with null for the `$object_type` parameter, and then assigning the tax when creating the custom post type and it worked as hoped-for. 
Codex updated.